# Confusion with notation of square bracket and round bracket of indices of a tensor

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Refer to the following picture:
[image]
I am confused with the last notation. Say if I got a tensor ${T^{abc}}_{de}$ and I would like to denote a new tensor which is defined by permuting the indices $a$ and $c$. But you just can't add an open bracket before $a$ and a closed bracket after $c$, because in the notation, it means permuting $a,b,c$ instead of just $a,c$ only.

So how should I do? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard notation for this. Maybe something like ${T^{(a|b|c)}}_{de}$?

Comment: But what if I want to do something like this: Given ${T^{abcdef}}_{gh}$, and I want to permute $a,e,f$ and $b,d$. If your notation is employed, then the new tensor should be denoted by ${T^{(a|(b|c|d)|ef)}}_{de}$. But this will confuse with the permutation of $a,d$ and $b,e,f$, so how can I deal with this?

Comment: Yeah, I was just referring to your specific situation. I don't know how to deal with this more complicated case.

Comment: You can not select $a,e,f$ and $b,d$ you should take two indices, do the exchange and then select another two, until you form what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose, $t^{abc}_{de}=U^{ac}⊗V^{b}_{de}$ with $U∈⊗^{2}T_{x}$, $V∈⊗T_{x}⊗^{2}T^{*}_{x}$ with $x∈M$, $M$ some underlying manifold. Then, $\widetilde{t}≑ U^{(ac)}⊗V^{b}_{de}$ and,
$\overline{t}≑ U^{[ac]}⊗V^{b}_{de}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).